# Display UIView behind SKScene in GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a basic SpriteKit game.

What I basically want to do is function `create_new_ui()` to create a `UIView` and to hide it behind the scene.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    create_new_ui()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView?
    {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        let scene = MainScene()

        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

func create_new_ui()
{
    let ui_view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    ui_view.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
    ui_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.view.addSubview(ui_view)
}
```

Can you tell me how can I move the `ui_view` behind the `SKScene`?

I tried `sendSubviewToBack(_:)` but had no effect. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try and use bringSubviewToFront(_:) on the SKScene after you added the new view

Comment: Tried. Without any effect.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: bringSubviewToFront(_:), to back, change layer.zPosition. If I understood correctly, view has only one subview (ui_view) which I created. The scene is not a subview.

Comment: Yes but where in the code did you try those?

Comment: After I created the scene, at the end of viewDidLoad().

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how presentScene is different from addSubview, but try and create the view after you add the scene, and then bring the view to the back or the scene to the front

Comment: Tried now, same result.

Comment: Damn I'm sorry I don't know what it could be then.

Comment: You are adding the view to the wrong part,  You need to make your `SKView` a child of your `UIView`.  You are currently trying to have your `UIView` as a child of your `SKView`  The hierarchy should be `ViewController -> UIView -> SKView`

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do it. One way is directly adding it to the window after view did appear.:

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    addFakeView()
   }

func addFakeView(){
    let fview = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 100))
    fview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.window?.insertSubview(fview, at: 0)
}
```